# Deploy a local modification of Node module to Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am developing some Cloud Functions for Firebase, and one in particular does not work to an issue in one of the node modules on which my function depend.

I already found where is the issue and how to fix it, the problem is that, if I modify the source in node_modules/ folder, that update is not sent to the server.
I removed from the package.json the dependency and did (before modify the file locally):

```
npm install --save pdf2img
```

But the function is not updated, the error is always the same. 
Is it possible to do what I would or not?

Thanks for anyone providing help!

Comment: no, don't modify files under node_modules directory, if you want to change something in an node_modules package you can fork the repository in GitHub were is most commonly to be found. Then modify it and have npm install from git repository. Also don't directly modify the package.json that way, the module will still exist because it was never removed, try npm to manage these actions.

Comment: Thanks mr.phoenix! So I'll fork and install that way. I'm not really expert with nodejs so will explore a bit more npm commands!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Mr.Phoenix hint, the solution is:

- Fork the repository (or in my case, find a fork that already has the fix).
- remove the previous version with:

> npm uninstal --save pdf2img

- Install the new version from the fork with:

> npm install --save git+https://git@github.com/matteocontrini/node-pdf2img

The problem in this specific case cannot be solved because the library relies on "gm" and other libraries that are not available in firebase functions

Answer (score 2):

1. Let say you made a change in a dependency called `protobufjs` in your `node_modules`.
2. Copy this package `protobufjs` from your `node_modules` to `functions` folder.
3. Add to your `dependencies` the following: `"protobufjs": "file:./protobufjs"` (assuming you placed the `protobufjs` folder in the root of functions folder).
4. Run: `firebase deploy`.

Comment: This is a good solution, there is no reason why someone should not be able to create a local copy of a package. There are benefits to this, regardless of whether you want your modification to be publicly accessible or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you have forked from the original repo to your own GitHub repo, you can clone your version into the root of your "functions" folder.
Then:

1. If the package needs to be compiled into Javascript from Typescript, build the package using either yarn (there will be a yarn.json file) or npm (there will be a package.json file).
2. Do as the previous answer by Daniel Danielecki suggested and add to your dependencies the following: "[YOUR-PACKAGE-NAME]": "file:./[YOUR-PACKAGE-NAME]"
3. Try to deploy using "firebase deploy". You might receive an es-lint error similar to - "eslint error - Cannot find module '@[SOME-NAME]/eslint-config'". This is a bug in eslint and can be viewed here [eslint bug](https://github.com/kentcdodds/kcd-scripts/issues/41#issuecomment-381264202). To fix this issue, simply add a ".eslintignore" file into the the root of your "functions" folder and add the line "[YOUR-PACKAGE-NAME]/*" to ignore the false linting errors for a successful deploy.